# File downloads not working in chrome which have Pepper-Flash 11.8.800.115

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

Users unable to download files through our flex website using Chrome which have Pepper Flash player plug-in. Downloads no longer working in Chrome from a navigateToUrl call in Flex. However if i disable the pepper flash plug-in in chrome then it works fine. Do you guys know any workaround to this issue?

Comment: Hmm, I know Pepper Flash has had it's issues... admittedly I hear about the problems less and less these days. But I have a hard time believing that Adobe/Google broke a simple `navigateToUrl()` call :) Could you share the relevant code to help us understand what is going on? You might also describe what happens. Do they get a 404 error? It downloads "garbage"? Or what?

Comment: Hi Sunil, thank you for the reply, here is the code                  
var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest(AppData.SERVICBASEEURL+"records/export_excel_vote?station_id="+AppData.station_id+"&id="+id);
navigateToURL(request,'_self');

when i click on the button to download the excel spreadsheet, it does nothing. it is not showing any 404 error or garbage.
I see a bug reported here

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3622211

Comment: Welcome to chrome, the all new IE6!! I have the same issue, going to report back when I find something

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Try use ExternalInterface.

In html in the JS section:

```
function downloadFileFromAS( _fileURL ) {
    window.location.href=_fileURL;
}
```

In AS3:

```
if( ExternalInterface.available ) {
    ExternalInterface.call( "downloadFileFromAS", fileUrlGoesHere );
}
```

Remember to set allowscriptaccess = "always" in html

It looks like it works at least for me.

Greg