# Flash AS3 download file using navigatetourl in chrome issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, download, navigatetourl

I am currently writing my first flash website and I have pretty much finished except for some niggly issues. I have some files that I would like to be downloadable and have used buttons that call navigateToURL(urlRequest, "_blank").

Now, the links work fine and navigate to the files correctly, however, in Chrome the tabs open but the downloads are not started. Simply refreshing the page or clicking on the address bar and pressing enter will start the downloads but obviously I want them to start automatically. In IE and Firefox, this is not an issue as the downloading starts fine.

Any ideas please?

Cheers

Comment: I just want to add that by running the swf file in GOM player, the download links open a chrome tab and begin the download as required...strange?

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568393/file-downloads-not-working-in-chrome-which-have-pepper-flash-11-8-800-115